# snmpget works but snmpset fails with No Such Instance currently exists at this OID

Tags: snmp

I am trying to set some OID but seems that it gives below error "**No Such Instance currently exists at this OID**" which should not be the case as i am able to get/walk same OID. so its present.

```
root@m-snm:~# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 10.2.4.19 .1.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3
iso.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3 = INTEGER: 1
root@m-snm:~# snmpset -v 2c -c public 10.2.4.19 .1.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.3 i 2
iso.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3 = **No Such Instance currently exists at this OID**
root@m-snm:~# snmpget -v 2c -c public 10.2.4.19 .1.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3
iso.3.6.1.x.x.x.x.x.7.3 = INTEGER: 1
```

Is it the permission issue ? Or i am not allowed to write ? or the field itself is not writable ? how can check what field are r/w and what are readonly

Comment: got any solution for this error?

Comment: was issue with my snmp setup  and in other case the linux distro itself was problem so u can try changing/updating existing that too

Comment: oh! I have already tried it on ubuntu 16 and 12 but same error. Setup was good as I'm getting expected values for default SNMP MIBS. But I have my own MIB to include.